# Removing an element from 2D char array in C

Tags: arrays, c, char, 2d

I have a 2D char array and I want to change all the occurrences of a particular element. For an example, I want to change all occurrences of `"ant"` to `"dummy"` without using structs.
Input `{"hello", "ant", "bird", "ant", "ant"}`
Output `{"hello", "dummy", "bird", "dummy", "dummy"}`

I want to implement this in C language and my code is shown below.`line` is the 2D array with words.

```
 for(int m = 0; m< tot; m++){
                if (!strcmp(line[m],"ant")){
                        printf("hit\n");
                        line[m]="dummy";
                    }
}
```

I am getting an error `assignment to expression with array type.`

Comment: You should use [`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) for copying strings.

Comment: The code shown would be more appropriate if the array were a 1D array of string pointers, but you say (not actually shown) that it is a 2D array.

Comment: @WeatherVane I am reading the words from a text file and it is stored as a 2D array